# best practice in drawing outline of image

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-canvas

I've tried 3 ways to make it, but the effect doesn't looks well.

1. copy and fill image then make offset. The demo is

```js
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
    img = new Image;

img.onload = draw;
img.src = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/UFBxY.png";

function draw() {

  var dArr = [-1,-1, 0,-1, 1,-1, -1,0, 1,0, -1,1, 0,1, 1,1], // offset array
      s = 20,  // thickness scale
      i = 0,  // iterator
      x = 5,  // final position
      y = 5;
  
  // draw images at offsets from the array scaled by s
  for(; i < dArr.length; i += 2)
    ctx.drawImage(img, x + dArr[i]*s, y + dArr[i+1]*s);
  
  // fill with color
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-in";
  ctx.fillStyle = "red";
  ctx.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width, canvas.height);
  
  // draw original image in normal mode
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
  ctx.drawImage(img, x, y);
}
```

```html
<canvas id=canvas width=500 height=500></canvas>
```

. When the outline width is large, the outline result will be wrong.

2. check the edge of image base on the Marching Squares algorithm. When the image shape is circle, the outline is with sawtooth. If make the outline more smoother, it won't fit the sharp shape like star.
3. copy and fill the image then scale it. When a image width is not equal with height, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

You can try with a math approach, without the offset array

```js
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
  img = new Image;

img.onload = draw;
img.src = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/UFBxY.png";

function draw() {
  var s = 20, // thickness scale
    x = 5, // final position
    y = 5;

  for (i=0; i < 360; i++)
    ctx.drawImage(img, x + Math.sin(i) * s, y + Math.cos(i) * s);

  // fill with color
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-in";
  ctx.fillStyle = "red";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  // draw original image in normal mode
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
  ctx.drawImage(img, x, y);
}
```

```html
<canvas id=canvas width=500 height=500></canvas>
```

My idea comes from the way we draw a circle using a string:
https://www.wikihow.com/Draw-a-Perfect-Circle-Using-a-Pin

Imagine that instead of a pencil at the end of the string we just have a shape

---

Here is a visual comparison of my approach and yours, also I'm showing a third approach scaling the image, there is really not a best one, it's just a matter of personal preference.

[image]

You could create a hybrid mode, if the hairline is important to you, get that portion of the image scaling it, then use a different way for the rest of the body.

Comment: Perfect! But the outline of hair is too smooth!

Comment: @liajoy take a look here: http://heldersepu.github.io/hs-scripts/HTML/canvasOutline.html I hope that gives you a bit of perspective what is going on behind the scenes

Comment: great! But if the image has no transparent area, the stroke will be sharp. Please see https://jsfiddle.net/wjuc746z/128/

Comment: @liajoy If you want to play with transparency use `globalAlpha` here is a fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/Lanr6vko/1/